# clicking is not working second time ng-click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angularjs

hi i am new to angularjs. in my requirement i got the exact data but clicking is not working for second time. i tried many ways but not working. please try  to solve my problem thanks in advance

```
$scope.click = function () {
    alert("hi");
    $scope.selected = "";              
    var x = $('#txtSearch').val();
    var _ReqObj = new Object();
    _ReqObj.id = x;
    _ReqObj.Meth = "CD";
    // alert(x);
    var httpreq = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "../Harneedi2/api/Home",
        data: _ReqObj
    }).success(function (response) {
        if (response == '') {
            alert('no data');
        }

        else {
            $scope.click = response;

            alert("data");
        }
    });
```

```
<button class="btn btn-default"  id="click" runat="server" type="submit" ng-click="click()"><i class="fa fa-search" style="color:brown;"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In else   block you are assigning `responce` to `$scop.click` varaible and click is your function

that's the problem with your code try this code may be this will help you

```
$scope.responce = {};
$scope.click = function () {
        alert("hi");
        $scope.selected = "";              
        var x = $('#txtSearch').val();
        var _ReqObj = new Object();
        _ReqObj.id = x;
        _ReqObj.Meth = "CD";
        // alert(x);
        var httpreq = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "../Harneedi2/api/Home",
            data: _ReqObj
        }).success(function (response) {
            if (response == '') {
                alert('no data');
            }

            else {
                //$scope.click = response; 

                 $scope.responce = response;
                alert("data");
            }
        });

<button class="btn btn-default"  id="click" runat="server" type="submit" ng-click="click()"><i class="fa fa-search" style="color:brown;"></i></button>
```

you are assign responce to click function that's your mistake.